# Currency vs Currencies

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> In the scientific literature we can find many attempts to discover the drivers of **cryptocurrency/cryptocurrencies** returns.

Which is better? Why?

Comment: The singular would probably be best. I can't tell for sure without more context, but the singular is typical and fits the sentence itself better.

Comment: @stangdon It partially answers, because I am talking about multiple specific cryptocurrencies, while a technology website talks about technology in general.
For example i would write "the returns of the cryptocurrencies"

Comment: @TheConfax  Yes, we would write "the returns of the cryptocurrencies", but in the phrase "cryptocurrency returns", *cryptocurrency* is a **noun adjunct**, and noun adjuncts are almost always singular: "horse race", not *horses race*; "skyscraper", not *skies scraper*.